# Sass is not working & Can't install ruby-sass on macOS Catalina

Tags: ruby, macos, sass, rubygems, macos-catalina

Ruby sass is not working after upgrading to macOS Catalina beta.

When I run `sudo gem install sass`, I'm getting an error:

````
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20191007-37566-177grvx.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.11.1/gem_make.out```
````

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Problem solved, here's the solution**

Open terminal & run these code

- Step 1: `brew update`
- Step 2: `xcode-select --install`
- Step 3: `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin sass`

Now check your sass version: `sass -v`

Comment: In addition to the above, I also installed the latest version of XCode and restarted.

I am not sure which steps are required but together, Sass is now finally back to working.

Thanks Delowar!

Comment: It fixed my problem too. Thank you

Comment: For anyone who decides to use this method, I **strongly** advise against it. Using sudo to install gems is a _bad_ idea

Answer (score 6):

Let me start by pressing people not to install gems with `sudo`. Since Catalina, user permissions changed for core/system files, which perfectly makes sense. This way no program can change the core files and they are save and secure.

Now the correct way to solve this issue is to install an additional Ruby build in your `home` folder which can be altered and tempered with.

1. `brew update && brew install rbenv ruby-build`
2. `xcode-select --install`
3. `vim ~/.zshenv`
4. add the following to the opened file `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"`
5. `vim ~/.zshrc`
6. add the following to the opened file:

```
source $HOME/.zshenv
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"
```

7. `source ~/.zshrc`
8. `rbenv install 2.6.4` or any version you feel comfortable with
9. `rbenv global 2.6.4`
10. `ruby -v` check current running ruby version
11. `ruby -e "puts (1..100).reduce(:+)"` outputs `5050`
12. Now install any gem you want `gem install sass`

Comment: This assumes user is running ZSH as their default shell.

Comment: Didn't Catalina drop bash for ZSH?

Comment: _zsh (Z shell) is the default shell **for all newly created user accounts**, starting with macOS Catalina._

Quoted from: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050 (emphasis mine)

Comment: I found this info: _**Ruby Sass was the original implementation of Sass, but it reached its end of life as of 26 March 2019.** It's no longer supported, and Ruby Sass users should migrate to another implementation._  (from https://sass-lang.com/ruby-sass, emphasis mine). Sounds like people should get Sass running without Ruby in future, right?

Answer (score 4):

Since macOS Catalina has removed ruby from the base install, you are no longer able to execute the sass executable installed via gem.

However, you can install Dart Sass as instructed on the [sass website](https://sass-lang.com/install):

> Install on Mac OS X (Homebrew)
>
> If you use [the Homebrew package manager](https://brew.sh/) for Mac OS X, you can install Dart Sass by running
>
> ```
> brew install sass/sass/sass
> ```

---

Before doing this however, it may be wise to uninstall the instance of sass that was installed via gem

```
gem uninstall sass
```

If you come across any issues with linking the sass that was installed via brew, you may need to manually link it (brew will usually tell you this if it is the case)

```
brew link --overwrite sass
```

Comment: For occasional users of Sass, like me: _Dart Sass is the primary implementation of Sass [...]. It compiles to pure JavaScript_ (see https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass)

Answer (score 0):

In my case several Ruby folders and files didn't have permissions to enter directories and read files.

- macOS Catalina 10.15.7
- ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]

```
{{ disable SIP Security }} 

$ sudo find /Library/Ruby/ -type d -exec chmod -v o+x {} +
$ sudo chmod -Rv go+r /Library/Ruby/

{{ enable SIP Security }}
```